# Newton-Raphson Division and Square Root Different Expressions for Different Precision

Tags: algorithm, math, assembly, floating-point

I am trying to compute the floating-point square root of x using assembly code using the newton-raphson method for first finding the inverse square root (1/sqrt(x)) and then multiplying by x to find sqrt(x).

However, I was reading the wikipedia page regarding newton-raphson division and it appears that depending on how you compute X_{i+1}, you will need a different amount of precision in intermediate steps.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Newton.E2.80.93Raphson_division):

> From a computation point of view the expressions X_{i+1} = X_i +
>   X_i(1-DX_i) and X_{i+1} = X_i(2-DX_i) are not equivalent. To obtain a
>   result with a precision of n bits while making use of the second
>   expression one must compute the product between X_i and (2-DX_i) with
>   double the required precision (2n bits). In contrast the product
>   between X_i and (1-DX_i) need only be computed with a precision of n
>   bits."

So, I have two questions:

1. I don't understand why one must compute the product between X_i and (2-DX_i) with double the required precision (2n bits) to obtain a result with a precision of n bits. Can someone please explain why?
2. Is there something similar that applies with Newton-Raphson Square Root? For instance, I am computing X_{i+1} = X_{i}(3/2 - 1/2 N X_{i}^2)  but this can also be computed as X_{i} + X_{i}(1/2 - 1/2 N X_{i}^2).  Does one expression require more intermediate precision, just like Newton-Raphson division does?  Is there a different format I should be using to require only n bits of precision to obtain a result with n bits of precision?

I am looking for a result with an error <= 1 ulp

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: @TedHopp, Which section in that document answers my question?

Comment: I think that the section on catastrophic cancellation would be relevant. It only addresses your first question, but you can apply the principles to the second. Other parts of the paper address reorganizing computations to improve accuracy.

Comment: @starbox The issue is that `D X_i` is going to be close to 1.  That means that intermediate round off error in `X_i ( 1 - D X_i )` is going to be in the last bits of a small floating point number, which will be small, so when added to `X_i` they disappear.  By contrast intermediate roundoff errors in `X_i ( 2 - D X_i )` appear in the last bits of the final number, so you need to carry calculations to higher precision then round at the end.

Comment: @btilly, Is there a similar principle for computing the square root? Where one expression requires less intermediate precision?

Comment: Please could you edit your question to clarify what level of accuracy you're looking for in the square root calculation.  Based on your past questions, I suspect that you're looking for a perfectly correctly-rounded result.  Is that correct, or are you content with a larger error than 0.5 ulp?

Comment: @MarkDickinson, Good point. I am looking for a result with an error <= 1 ulp, I updated the question per your request.

Comment: @starbox Yes, there is.  The issue in both cases is, "precise number + product close to 0" has less floating point multiplication roundoff issues than "product close to precise number".

Comment: Changed language tags to match question (assembly).